# Laravel: Update route without page refresh

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a page that lists down all todo items stored in a database. The page / view is returned by a controller *TodoListController.php*.

```
public function index()
{
    // `TodoList` is the model, ie extends Eloquent.
    $todo_lists = TodoList::all();
    return View::make('todos.index')->with('todo_lists', $todo_lists);
}
```

What I am trying to do is to add a link that will open up a lightbox for editing an existing todo. Each todo has its own edit link; that is, one link corresponds to one todo item. Once opened, I'd also want to pre-populate the form fields with existing data / values. Upon success clicking the 'Edit' button), the lightbox should close and we immediately reflect the page with the new values ie *no* page refresh.

Questions:

1. If I linked the edit form to an update route eg `Form::model($list, array('route' => ['todos.update', $list->id], 'method' => 'PUT'))`, the page would have to refresh, right?
2. Would it be more advisable to do this via AJAX? Or, maybe that's the only way in order to avoid page refresh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, javascript/ajax is the only way to update page data without refreshing the page

You'll want to populate the lightbox form using data from the page (or data from an AJAX POST), then when the user submits the form, make an ajax request to your update route, and finally update the page with the data the user entered.

Comment: That's sad -- we cannot utilize the Laravel `Validator` to check against the submitted values eg `$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), /* some rules */);`

Comment: User data -> HTML Form -> Javascript AJAX request -> PHP (updater route) -> Laravel Validator -> MySQL. If the validator fails the updater route can return an HTTP error

Comment: _... -> Laravel Validator -> ..._ Can we use `Input::all()` to access input data passed by AJAX?

Comment: Yes, an AJAX POST request is exactly the same as if the user submitted an html form.